# Where is the source for Oracle JDK 11 sun.security.ssl?

Tags: java, ssl, handshake

I'm using Oracle JDK version 11.0.16+11-LTS-199.

I'm trying to learn about SSL handshakes from looking at the code but the line numbers in the stack traces do not match any source code I can find.  The source for the sun.security.ssl package is not in src.zip.

I cloned the jdk11u repo from GitHub but the closest tag is jdk-11.0.16+8.  There is no 11.

I can't paste a stack trace here (pasting seems to be disabled) but an example line from a stack trace is:

```
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:718)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:579)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:503)
```

However line 503 in the source I have is a different method.  BaseSSLSocketImpl is also in the stack trace but it seems to match what I see in GitHub.

Comment: Can you please add few more lines from stack trace

Comment: I doubt that you will find sourcecode from Oracle SDK on github or any other open source plattform. If you don't find the source inside the included src.zip from the JDK, you probably will have to have a paid support license from Oracle to obtain it. And no, there is no SSLSocketImpl.java inside the freely downloadable version of Oracle JDK 11

Comment: @cyberbrain: yes you will. Back in the 90s Sun's JDK included source, licensed only for debugging, of the standard library defined by the spec and TCK -- which excluded cryptoproviders because of the legal hassle involved then in exporting crypto from the US. In the late 00s Sun open-sources (basically GPL) all but a few parts of Java, producing OpenJDK which _does_ include the cryptoproviders. Originally Sun/Oracle ran its own repostories, but they have now moved to github -- which does have these classes, but not the specific version OP needs.

Comment: John: can/would you use one of the other OpenJDK builders instead of Oracle? In particular [Corretto](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/releases) and [Temurin](https://adoptium.net/temurin/archive/?version=11) have versions that better match the openjdk project on github and also offer downloadable source archives matched to each built release.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 as the file in question (`SSLSocketImpl.java`) is not contained in the "src.zip" I really doubt that it was released as open source. It is also in the vendor specific top level package `sun` which drops probabilities further. OpenJDK sources are really a better choice, but maybe it will be a different class here to search for.